# Find a key value in json array of objects and return another key value with angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

How can I loop through my json data to find two specific key values e.g. weight = "8m" and meters = "7t" then return the name value of the object where these two  values are found e.g. "25t".

data.json (Small sample)

```
    [
      {
       "name": "20t",
       "weight": ["1t","2t","3t","4t","5t"],
       "meters": ["7m","8m","9m","10m","12m","14m","16m","18m"]
      },
      {
       "name": "25t",
       "weight": ["1t","2t","3t","4t","5t","6t","7t","8t"],
       "meters": ["7m","8m","9m","10m","12m","14m","16m","18m","20m","22m"]
      }
    ]
```

I'm able to loop through all the data using ngif and ngfor.

```
    <div *ngIf="crane?.length">
      <div *ngFor="let data of crane">

        <p>{{data.name}}</p>
        <p>{{data.weight}}</p>
        <p>{{data.meters}}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
```

But I need to output only the specific name value where the weight and meters match the key value I want. Any idea on how I could achieve this? I'm quite new to angular, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add output of example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
      {
       "name": "20t",
       "weight": ["1t","2t","3t","4t","5t"],
       "meters": ["7m","8m","9m","10m","12m","14m","16m","18m"]
      },
      {
       "name": "25t",
       "weight": ["1t","2t","3t","4t","5t","6t","7t","8t"],
       "meters": ["7m","8m","9m","10m","12m","14m","16m","18m","20m","22m"]
      }
    ]

const w = "7t";
const m = "8m";

const filteredData = data
            .filter(
              (data) => 
                  data.weight
                    .some((weight) => weight === w) 
                  && 
                  data.meters
                    .some((meter) => meter === m)
              );

const keys = filteredData.map((data) => data.name);

console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hanged some of your sentence it did not make a lot of sense compared to the provided data but it looks like this:

```
const data = [
      {
        "name": "20t",
        "weight": ["1t", "2t", "3t", "4t", "5t"],
        "meters": ["7m", "8m", "9m", "10m", "12m", "14m", "16m", "18m"]
      },
      {
        "name": "25t",
        "weight": ["1t", "2t", "3t", "4t", "5t", "6t", "7t", "8t"],
        "meters": ["7m", "8m", "9m", "10m", "12m", "14m", "16m", "18m", "20m", "22m"]
      }
    ]
    //ow can I loop through my json data to find two specific key values e.g. weight = "8t" and meters = "7m" then return the name value of the object where these two values are found e.g. "25t".

    const result = data.filter(a => a.weight.find(w => w == "8t"))
      .filter(a => a.meters.find(m => m == "7m"))
      .map(a => a.name);
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: This works, however, setting the variables beforehand gives much more flexibility, many thanks